# NGINX conflicting server name "www.domain.com" on 0.0.0.0:80

Tags: nginx, ssl, dns

I have 2 domains which I want to connect to one folder. The first one worked and when I did the second one a few weeks later, the following error came up:

```
conflicting server name "domain" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

I also have Django projects on the same server and a file in which I have the line of code already used:

```
listen 80;
```

I don't know if it can be because of that.

I also hat SSL Certificates from Certbot on both Domains but removed the code from the file.

This is my full code:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain.de www.domain.de;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/Domain.error.log;

    root /var/www/domain.de;

    index index.html;

    location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
     }

}
```

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire Nginx configuration across all included files - you should be able to identify the cause of the duplicated `server_name` directive.

Comment: @RichardSmith thank you! With that method I could find the file with the duplicate!